# jQuery UI Datepicker Problem with arrival - depart dates

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, daterangepicker

Argh.. I am stumped....

I have a reservation module that is running the jQuery date-picker UI. I have an arrival date field and a departure date field each with a date-picker object initiated on both.

I want the default arrival date to be todays date I achieved this by doing the following:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

          $(".arrive").datepicker();
          $(".depart").datepicker();

          $(".arrive").datepicker('setDate', new Date());

      });
   </script>
```

That works perfectly however when a user selects an arrival date I then want the departure default date to be set as one day after the users selected arrival date. I tried using the onSelect events for the date-picker object and tried to pull the value from the arrival field and add a day but to no avail. I have seen this functionality before, I don't think it is very difficult I am just beyond stumped on this one. Any ideas? My html for the text fields is as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li>  
    <label>Arriving</label>     
    <span class="dateinput">                                                   
        <input class="arrive" type="text" value="" name="startDate" />                                  
        <img id="arrive"  src="images/calendar_icon.png"  />
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </span>
  </li>

  <li>  
    <label>Departing</label>        
    <span class="dateinput">                                
        <input class="depart" name="endDate" value="" type="text"  />               
        <img src="images/calendar_icon.png" />
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </span> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks a bunch to whoever can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range) as inspiration:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".arrive").datepicker({
          onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            // Parse the selected date
            var instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                    selectedDate, instance.settings );

            // Add one day
            date.setDate(date.getDate()+1);

            // Set the new date
            $(".depart").datepicker('setDate', date);               
        }
      });
      $(".depart").datepicker();

      $(".arrive").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm glad, can you accept my post as the answer? It will give me reputation points and people will be more willing to answer your questions if you accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

did you have a look at the documentation?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

-> view source

it even got some onSelect-code you could partly use for your specific problem

Answer (score 0):

after some trial and error found this worked well for me to set a min departure date and max arrival date (in case departure selected before arrival)

```
$("#arrival").datepicker({
  //set other options here
  minDate: 0,  //sets min date today
  onClose: function() {
    let arriveDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
    if(arriveDate){
      arriveDate.setDate(arriveDate.getDate() + 1);
      $("#depart").datepicker("option", "minDate", arriveDate); //sets min departure date to arrival date + 1
    }else $("#depart").datepicker("option", "minDate", 1); //reset to default min departure date (in case arrival date was earlier set and later removed)
  }
})
$("#depart").datepicker({
  //set other options here
  minDate: 1,  //sets min date today + 1
  onClose: function() {
    let departDate = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
    if(departDate){
      departDate.setDate(departDate.getDate() - 1);
      $("#arrival").datepicker("option", "maxDate", departDate); //sets max arrival date to departure date - 1
    }else $("#arrival").datepicker("option", "maxDate", ''); //reset to default max arrival date (in case departure date was earlier set and later removed)

  }
})
```